# Проблема с установкой phpword через composer

Tags: php, composer, phpword

Помогите, пожалуйста, не могу найти в чем проблема, при установке `phpword` через `composer` выдает ошибку:

> C:\xampp\PHPWord-develop>composer require phpoffice/phpword
>
> Using version ^0.14.0 for phpoffice/phpword
>   ./composer.json has been updated
>   Loading composer repositories with package information
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>   Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>       - The requested package phpoffice/phpword No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by phpoffice/phpword[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "phpoffice/phpword": "^0.14.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте `composer require phpoffice/phpword "^0.14.0"`

Comment: @RTK не помогает

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос секцию **require** из вашего **composer.json**

Comment: а просто запуск **composer update** не помогает?